# Searching in map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How can i search for specific object in map that has been built using rviz ?
Can I use a specific algorithm?
or can I do this using rviz?

any help?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58825/searching-in-map/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably read up on some basic concepts regarding rviz, gmapping and generally "how stuff in ROS works :)" (the tutorials are a good start).

Rviz is the ROS Visualizer and mainly is useful for visualizing the robot and environment state. It does neither build maps, nor does it provide algorithms for searching for objects in them. It just allows you to visualize the map it receives from somewhere else (for example gmapping).

That being said, I am not aware of a existing approach that performs some kind of object recognition on occupancy grid maps (if that is what you require).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-03-21**:
Thanks :) , but what i mean is how my robot can walk Automatic and freely in the map that has been built using rviz without neglecting parts of the map

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-03-21**:
That sounds completely different to your original question :) For navigation inside a map you can use the navigation stack. To automatically explore an environment you can have a look at the exploration stack or the hector_exploration_planner

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-03-21**:
Sorry for the inconvenience :) , but I built the map using gmapping..
Are these methods can be beneficial to me?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-03-21**:
If you want your robot to navigate in that map, you can use the navigation stack. If you have a walking robot, that complicates things though, as the navigation stack is originally intended to be used with wheeled robots.

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-03-22**:
Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no simple solution. We need to write a new code which contains:

1. Visual recognition of the object (e.g. juice, book) that the robot tries to recognize. This may be the most difficult part and I am still not sure which libraries are the most suitable. Perhaps RoboEarth detector?
2. Navigation implementation (not by rviz but directly from the code) which calls gmapping, acml, move_base, etc.
3. Main: the strategy designed by you (e.g. circulate the room according to a particular trajectory; when it sees the book then turns right, etc.) Alternatively you may try Exploration stack.

Actually I am trying to do the same thing. Perhaps we can help each other :-)

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-03-22**:
Thanks :)
If i got good results ,i will put it here :)